# How to let Google Cloud Composer (airflow) run jobs on a different kubernetes cluster?

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I want to have my Cloud Composer environment (Google Cloud's managed Apache Airflow service) start pods on a **different** kubernetes cluster. How should I do this?

*Note that Cloud composer runs airflow on a kubernetes cluster. That cluster is considered to be the composer "environment". Using the default values for the `KubernetesPodOperator`, composer will schedule pods on its own cluster. However in this case, I have a different kubernetes cluster on which I want to run the pods.*

I can connect to the worker pods and run a `gcloud container clusters get-credentials CLUSTERNAME` there, but every now and then the pods get recycled so this is not a durable solution.

I noticed that the [`KubernetesPodOperator`](https://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/kubernetes_pod_operator/index.html#airflow.contrib.operators.kubernetes_pod_operator.KubernetesPodOperator) has both an `in_cluster` and a `cluster_context` argument, which seem useful. I would expect that this would work:

```py
pod = kubernetes_pod_operator.KubernetesPodOperator(
    task_id='my-task',
    name='name',
    in_cluster=False,
    cluster_context='my_cluster_context',
    image='gcr.io/my/image:version'
)
```

But this results in `kubernetes.config.config_exception.ConfigException: Invalid kube-config file. Expected object with name CONTEXTNAME in kube-config/contexts list`

Although if I run `kubectl config get-contexts` in the worker pods, I can see the cluster config listed.

So what I fail to figure out is:

- how to make sure that the context for my other kubernetes cluster is available on the worker pods (or should that be on the nodes?) of my composer environment?
- if the context is set (as I did manually for testing purposes), how can I tell airflow to use that context?

Comment: Check out the GKEPodOperator. https://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/gcp_container_operator/index.html

Comment: @ECris that works! Feel free to post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Cool! Glad it helped!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [GKEPodOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/_api/airflow/contrib/operators/gcp_container_operator/index.html) for this.

Example usage from the docs :

```
operator = GKEPodOperator(task_id='pod_op',
                          project_id='my-project',
                          location='us-central1-a',
                          cluster_name='my-cluster-name',
                          name='task-name',
                          namespace='default',
                          image='perl')
```